# PostgreSQL remove duplicates by GROUP BY

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-order-by, distinct, greatest-n-per-group

I would like to print the last message of a person, but only his latest message should be printed per person. I use PostgreSQL 10.

```
+-----------+----------+--------------+
| name      |   body   |  created_at  |
+-----------+----------+--------------+
| Maria     | Test3    |  2017-07-07  |
| Paul      | Test5    |  2017-06-01  |
+-----------+----------+--------------+
```

I have tried this with the following SQL query, this gives me exactly that back but unfortunately the people are doubled in it.

```sql
SELECT * FROM messages 
WHERE receive = 't'
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY MAX(created_at) DESC
```

```
+-----------+----------+--------------+
| name      |   body   |  created_at  |
+-----------+----------+--------------+
| Maria     | Test1    |  2016-06-01  |
| Maria     | Test2    |  2016-11-01  |
| Maria     | Test3    |  2017-07-07  |
| Paul      | Test4    |  2017-01-01  |
| Paul      | Test5    |  2017-06-01  |
+-----------+----------+--------------+
```

I tried to remove the duplicates with a DISTINCT, but unfortunately I get this error message:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT ON (name) * FROM messages 
WHERE receive = 't'
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY MAX(created_at) DESC
```

```
ERROR: SELECT DISTINCT ON expressions must match initial ORDER BY expressions LINE 1: SELECT DISTINCT ON (name) * FROM messages ^ : SELECT DISTINCT ON (name) * FROM messages WHERE receive = 't' GROUP BY name ORDER BY MAX(created_at) DESC
```

**Do you have any ideas how I can solve this ?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would use `DISTINCT ON` as follows:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (name) * 
FROM messages 
WHERE receive = 't'
ORDER BY name, created_at DESC
```

That is:

- no `GROUP BY` clause is needed
- the column(s) listed in `DISTINCT ON(...)` must appear first in the `ORDER BY` clause
- ... followed by the column that should be use to break the group (here, that is `created_at`)

Note that the results of a `distinct on` query are always sorted by columns in the clause (because this sort is what is used to identifiy which rows should be kept).

If you want more control over the sort order, then you can use window functions instead:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT m.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY name ORDER BY created_at DESC) rn
    FROM messages m
    WHERE receive = 't'
) t
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY created_at DESC
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `DISTINCT ON`, but with the right `ORDER BY`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (name) m.*
FROM messages m
WHERE receive = 't'
ORDER BY name, created_at DESC;
```

In general, you don't use `DISTINCT ON` with `GROUP BY`.  It is used with `ORDER BY`.  The way it works is to that it chooses the first row for each `name` based on the `ORDER BY` clause.

You should not be thinking of what you are doing as aggregation.  You want to filter based on the `created_at`.  In many databases, you would express this using a correlated subquery:

```
select m.*
from messages m
where m.created_at = (select max(m2.created_at)
                      from messages m2
                      where m2.name = m.name and m2.receive = 't'
                     ) and
      m.receive = 't';   -- this condition is probably not needed
```

Comment: But then it's sorted by name.

When I try to do this with the subquery the newest entries are missing. Why is this so?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * 
FROM messages 
WHERE receive = 't' and not exists (
    select 1
    from messages m
    where m.receive = message.receive and messages.name = m.name and m.created_at > messages.created_at
)
ORDER BY created_at DESC
```

The query above finds the messages which fulfill the following criteria:

- receive is 't'
- there not exists another message which

  - has the same value for receive
  - has the same name
  - and is newer

Assuming that the same name does not send two messages at exactly the same time this should be enough. Another point to make is that the name might look similar, but be different, if some white characters are present inside the value, so, if you see two records in the result with the same name, but with different created_at in the query above, then it is highly probable that white characters are playing tricks on you.